Do normally closed solid state relays require current to remain closed? (CPC1106N)
I’d like to use a normally closed SSR to rather quickly discharge a capacitor through a resistor when a circuit is powered down. So, open when the circuit is powered, closed when not powered. I’ve been thinking of using one of these:
datasheet
But I see under input characteristics that “input current to deactivate” is 0.05A. Does that mean that it requires 0.05A to stay closed? In other words, when this thing has no current at all through the LED, will this still connect my cap to the resistor?



Do normally closed solid state relays require current to remain
closed?

No, and neither does the one you linked (short answer). Here's a better view of that page of the data sheet with more sections shown: -


In the red boxes: with zero current into the input diode, the load current can be up to 75 mA
In the purple boxes: the on-resistance is typically 3.85 Ω when the input current is zero and, if you raised the input current to 0.5 mA, the output would be off with a leakage current of up to 1 μA
The green boxes tell you that you must reach or exceed 0.5 mA to guarantee that the output goes to an off-state and, that you must reduce the input current to (or below) 0.05 mA to guarantee that the output goes to an on-state (normally closed)


Does that mean that it requires 0.05A to stay closed?

No, it means that the input current has to be at or below 0.05 mA to guarantee the output is in the on-state and, of course, 0.0000 mA is below 0.05 mA.

The term "normally-closed" means that the relay is closed by default, and requires current to open it. If current were required to close the relay, it would be called normally-open, not normally-closed.
Internally, these work by using depletion mode MOSFETs instead of enhancement mode ones. Depletion mode devices are on by default, and require a nonzero gate voltage to turn off.
The "input current to deactivate" rating means that dropping the input current to anywhere below 50 μA (including 0 A) is guaranteed to turn the part off. If your input current is 51 μA, it's not guaranteed to turn off. It's as simple as that.

The name solid state relay indicates that this device does not require any energy to keep its current state. So if you’ve put energy into it to open the contact and then remove power completely it will stay open (solid state).
What you need is a normal relay which you will have to power during operation to keep the contact open and when it powers down the contact will close the discharge circuit.
Edit:
I‘ve looked at the full datasheet for this device. I didn’t know of semiconductors called SSR.
In this case the term solid state feels wrong because if the control current drops below the stated threshold the state will return to „closed“. So very not like a mechanical SSR which i was thinking about.

@They’re new to me as well. Maybe by solid state they mean “no mechanical or moving parts”? Solid state drives for example. For my application, I want the relay to return to closed, after being powered off completely. That’s the question pretty much. It’s called a “normally closed” SSR which sounds promising but I need to know if it will stay closed when given 0V.

There is no such thing as a "mechanical SSR"; a solid state relay is inherently a semiconductor device. You seem to have it mixed up with the term "latching relay".

@Hearth I was referring to mechanical relays.

@BobaJFET But your question is about solid-state relays, not mechanical relays. "solid state" specifically means not mechanical.
